# Conexão app com firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

Boa tarde, estou com o seguinte erro no meu logcat, ao tentar registrar um e-mail e senha no authentication do firebase, onde pula para o meu "else" de "Alert" e logo após o erro no "logcat"

erro: "E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted"

Teste realizado no dispositivo samsung com android Oreo 8.0, vi algo relacionado a permissões nessa versão não tenho certeza se seria isso o motivo do erro.

segue o código da minha classe de conexão, registro e gradle App.

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Conexao {

private static FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private static  FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
private static FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

private  Conexao(){
}

public static FirebaseAuth getFirebaseAuth(){
    if(firebaseAuth==null){
        inicializarFirebaseAuth();
    }
    return firebaseAuth;
}

private static void inicializarFirebaseAuth(){
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    authStateListener =  new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user!= null){
                firebaseUser = user;
            }

        }
    };
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener((authStateListener));
}

public static FirebaseUser getFirebaseUser(){
return firebaseUser;
}

public static void logOut(){
    firebaseAuth.signOut();

}
}
```

Activity de registro do meu usuário:

```
public class RegistroPessoaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private Button btnCadastrar;
private EditText dtNascimento;
private EditText nome;
private EditText email;
private EditText senha;
private EditText confiSenha;
private FirebaseAuth auth;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    auth = Conexao.getFirebaseAuth();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro_pessoa);

    dtNascimento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textData);
    nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Nome);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Email);
    senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_CadSenha);
    confiSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_ConfiSenha);
    btnCadastrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cadastrar);

   /* String [] countries={"  ","Fisíca", "Jurídica"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String> 
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,countries);
    editSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);*/

    SimpleMaskFormatter Maskdata = new SimpleMaskFormatter("NN/NN/NNNN");
    MaskTextWatcher DataText = new MaskTextWatcher(dtNascimento, Maskdata);
    dtNascimento.addTextChangedListener(DataText);

    btnCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String Senha = senha.getText().toString().trim();
            String Nome = nome.getText().toString().trim();
            String ConfiSenha = confiSenha.getText().toString().trim();
            String DtNascimento = dtNascimento.getText().toString().trim();
            criarUser(Email, Senha);

        }
    });

}
private void alert(String msg){

Toast.makeText(RegistroPessoaActivity.this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

private void criarUser(String email, String senha){

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,senha).addOnCompleteListener(RegistroPessoaActivity.this,
            new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                alert("Usuario cadastrado com sucesso");
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegistroPessoaActivity.this, PerfilActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }else{
                alert("Erro ao cadastrar usuario");
            }
        }
    });

}

}
```

Agora o  Gradle do meu app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.com.softtech.eufaco"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
   buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASEtxt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
  }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'

}
dependencies {
  implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
implementation "com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0"
implementation 'com.github.rtoshiro.mflibrary:mflibrary:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Quem poder por favor estou com uma certa urgência agradeço toda e qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro inicialize o Firebase no onCreate:

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Tente capturar as exceções lançadas no momento do cadastro de um novo usuário:

```
private void criarUser(String email, String senha){

auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,senha).addOnCompleteListener(RegistroPessoaActivity.this,
        new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            alert("Usuario cadastrado com sucesso");
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistroPessoaActivity.this, PerfilActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }else {
            String excecao;

            try{
                throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
            }
            catch (FirebaseNetworkException ex){
                excecao = "Verifique sua conexão com a internet.";
            }
            catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException ex){
                excecao = "Senha fraca. Utilize ao menos seis caracteres contendo letras e números.";
            }
            catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException ex){
                excecao = "E-mail já cadastrado.";
            }
            catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException ex){
                excecao = "O e-mail fornecido é inválido.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                excecao = "Erro ao tentar cadastrar.";
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            alert("excecao");
    }
});
```

}

Você também pode debugar e ver o que o método `Conexao.getFirebaseAuth()` está retornando. Também partimos do pressuposto que você pediu permissão para usar internet no seu manifesto e está com o método de autenticação por email e senha ativado no Firebase Console.

Comment: Sim, o manifesto, já esta com a permissão de internet definido sim e método configurado.

Comment: Conseguiu algum avanço?